# Customize orders adding topics for orders on flutter

Tags: flutter

i am makin an app for a restauranti had some troubles when i customize order adding some details for example light ketchup or no onion etc... i create a List for intstructions

```
List ketchup = [
'No',
'light',
'regular',
'extra',
];
```

and i used  a listtile for them picture is on below

[image: this is screen shot of it]

and i need to listen when if they choosed (light or no ,regular etc...) i should print it or how can i read that  if you have any suggestions thanks a lot

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:resat/BurgerListView/data/toppics_model.dart';
  import 'data/toppics.dart';

 class decor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
 return new MyAppState();
   }
 }


   class MyAppState extends State<decor> {

 List ketchup = [
'No',
'light',
'regular',
'extra',
  ];
  List calori = ['0 Cal', '1 Cal', '2 Cal', '3 Cal'];
 var i = 2;


 final List<topics> _topics = categories;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build

return Container(

    margin: EdgeInsets.all(6), //space between other listtiles
    decoration: BoxDecoration(

        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),

    child: ListTile(

        title: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
              child:
              Text("Ketchup\n" + calori[i], textAlign: TextAlign.center,),),
          Expanded(
            child: (InkWell(
              child: Text("-", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (i <= 0) {
                    i = i;
                  } else
                    i--;
                });
              },
            )),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Text(ketchup[i], textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
          Expanded(
            child: (InkWell(
              child: Text("+", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (i > 2) {
                    i = i;
                  } else
                    i++;
                });
              },
            )),
          ),

        ]),

        leading: Icon(Icons.pie_chart))
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to observe some change in data [`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) is one of the best option in flutter. [***Here***](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/32629ed5d1597af4460946ed3540d0c0) is a demo that you can refer to understand working of [`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html).

In your code you can create a [`ValueNotifier<List<String>>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and can observe the changes in it.(`List<String>` is for your ketchup list).

[`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) is used to rebuild a Widget when ValueNotifier receives a change. If you want to observe ValueNotifier change for your backend code then you can use [addListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/addListener.html) method for it.

I hope this helps you, in case of any doubt please comment.